# How to develop a JayData query based on OData provider with any-all support for list{String}

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, odata, jaydata, datajs

Consider the following JayData entities:

```
           var Todo = $data.Entity.extend("Todo", {
                Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
                Task: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 },
                DueDate: { type: Date },
                Completed: { type: Boolean },
                Person: { type: "Person", required: true, inverseProperty: "Todos" }
            });

            var Person = $data.Entity.extend("Person", {
                Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
                Name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 },
                Todos: { type: $data.Array, elementType: Todo, inverseProperty: "Person" },
                OtherNames : { type : $data.Array, elementType: String }
            });
```

Each person has many ***Todo*** items.

And now I can load people who have at least one completed todo. (With JayData 1.3.4 & Web API & OData 5.6 and IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2).

Take a look at the sample which is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ysmoradi/P59jz/5/

But I want to run another query which is a little more different than this one.

I'd like to load people who have special names in their **List{String}** of *OtherNames*

Sample of OData query of my problem that works fine:

```
People?$filter=OtherNames/any(name:name eq 'AAA' or name eq 'BBB');
```

How can I accomplish this OData query within JayData in any possible way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can express the OData **any** query operator with the **some()** JayData operator.
The documentation of the every() and some() operators of JayData can be found here - [Using some() and every() with JayData OData provider](http://jaydata.org/blog/using-some-and-every-with-jaydata-odata-provider)

Comment: Thanks, I've developed the sample code of my jsfiddle from that documentation and it works fine, and I've used that a lot in my application before, but my new scenario is a little different than usual. I don't want to apply any on List<Phone> or List<Person>, I want to use List<String>. I've tried to use some and every, but It does not work. Could you please suggest me which syntax in JayData should I use to have following output ? People?$filter=OtherNames/any(name:name eq 'AAA' or name eq 'BBB'); Note that here 'OtherNames' is List<String>, and when I use some or every it says not supported!